# Linux User NameSpaces

Tags: linux, go, linux-namespaces

I am experimenting with user namespaces using Go on Linux. The thing that I cannot figure out is that although am setting the uid and gid mappings when creating the namespace it still identifies as the *nobody* user  when I launch the binary using *sudo* but when I launch it using the normal user everything works fine. For reference please see my code below

```
...
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/sh")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
        Cloneflags: syscall.CLONE_NEWUSER,
        UidMappings: []syscall.SysProcIDMap{
            {
                ContainerID: 0,
                HostID:      1000,
                Size:        1,
            },
        },
        GidMappings: []syscall.SysProcIDMap{
            {
                ContainerID: 0,
                HostID:      1000,
                Size:        1,
            },
        },
    }
    cmd.Run()

....
...
```

From the host I can confirm that indeed the user and group mappings were successful. The current pid is *87751*

```
sudo cat /proc/87751/uid_map
         0       1000          1
sudo cat /proc/87751/gid_map
         0       1000          1
```

But when I run the binary after building

```
go build -o user_n
sudo ./user_n
sh-5.0$ whoami 
nobody
sh-5.0$ id
uid=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nobody) groups=65534(nobody) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

But when I run the binary using the normal user it works as expected

```
./user_n
sh-5.0# whoami
root
sh-5.0# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),65534(nobody) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

While running the binary using the normal user is an option I would like to know why running using *sudo* does not give the expected results. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

More info

```
Fedora 31
Kernel 5.3.11-100.fc29.x86_64
go version go1.14.3 linux/amd64
```

Comment: In the first case, you are running as root user (sudo) for which there is no mapping in the child user namespace. Hence, the "nobody" id. In the second case, you run the program as id 1000 for which the mapping says : 1000 becomes root in the child user namespace.

Comment: @RachidK.: Is that okay to post as an answer? It looks complete enough to me.

Comment: @Ry-: I am OK. Am I supposed to make it  ? (I am only 1 week old in StackOverflow, I don't know all the rules)

Comment: @RachidK.: You don’t have to, but I don’t see why not! I’d vote for it. :)

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, you are running as root user (through sudo) for which there is no mapping specified in the child user namespace. Hence, the resulting "nobody" id.

In the second case, you run the program as user id 1000 for which the mapping says : 1000 becomes root in the child user namespace. Hence, the resulting "root" id.

Comment: Thanks . So does this mean that a process cannot make mappings to any arbitrary user id that exists on the host. i.e the process doing the mapping  can only map to the user id that owns it ? @Rachid K

Comment: A user can map himself into any user in a child namespace. To add other mappings, you need to use so-called setuid helpers like newuidmap and newgidmap.

Comment: @MichaelMwangi: That’s not what it means. You added an entry for `HostID: 1000`, which isn’t your UID when running with sudo (i.e. as root). Add another entry for `HostID: 0`, or (probably better) drop privileges back to 1000 before running the command.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Let me look at it again from that angle @RachidK.